# Can I trigger a click action when an email to case case is submitted?

Tags: trigger, email2case, url

When an email to case is generated for a specific case origin, I would like to also trigger a click action to a URL that is coded to create an external case in a different system. Note: this URL is coded to when clicked from the same case, it automatically ties it to the existing case.

Current process is a case is generated from email to case, a rep then goes to that case and clicks a button that has a URL coded to link it to the open case. I would like to automate this process because the email to case cases will always need to click that button to sync to an external ticketing system.

Note: Need the case created in SFDC and need it created in the other tool linked to the SFDC case which is done automatically via the URL provided.

Comment: If you know what the URL is when the e-mail is generated, can you just submit a request to the URL? It seems like hacking the click event is probably not the best way to do this.  Is the URL part of a REST service?

Comment: Sounds like a great use case for Outbound messages if the external system can handle XML. If not, use an @future method to send the info after you have create the case. You cannot simulate a button click but you can replicate what the button is doing in code

Comment: echoing @Eric here - this is a design problem with the original button. You need a `service` that sync's the case to the external system and there are various clients of that service: (1) a Custom button on Case Detail and (2) The Domain layer on Case (i.e. trigger handler or workflow/process builder)